# Using a custom hook to fetch API data in React componentm, API response persists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, fetch

I am using a hook in order to refactor fetch logic that may be repeated across multiple React components. The logic of the hook itself is relatively generic and mapped out as follows.
It is designed to return a response, potential error and update isLoading from true to false once a response is fulfilled.

```
const useFetch = (url, options = {}) => {

  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  console.log("again running useFetch")

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();

  }, []);

  return { response, error, isLoading };
};
```

Now here is how I am using it with in my React component,

```
function CardTable() {

  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const url = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/"


  const data = useFetch(url)
  console.log(data.response)
  //{success: true, deck_id: 'mnpedlyiolj7', cards: Array(1), remaining: 51}
  
  const addCard = async () => {
 
    setCards(cards => [...cards, { ...data.response, id: uuid() }]);
  };
```

It is almost working, my understanding is that data is assigned the value of calling our useFetch hook function at each rendering of our Cardtable component. However the same response data is returned each time I make the fetch request to the API.
There must be something I am missing here, any ideas?
Your help is always appreciated.

I have tried multiple ways to re-iterate the API call, to draw the card from the API request, but the same result persists. This is evident in the remaining property of response.data which remains and persists at 51, despite multiple API requests.

Comment: your approach seems good but have a look at TanStack Query, this will save you a lot of headaches and effort

Comment: I think you just need to do the right object destructuring, that is it, to get the accurate data from the custom hook.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified  code :

```
const useFetch = (url, options = {}, trigger) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true); 
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
      setIsLoading(false); completes
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url, options, trigger]); 

  return { response, error, isLoading };
};
```

and

```
function CardTable() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [triggerFetch, setTriggerFetch] = useState(0); 

  const url = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/";

  const data = useFetch(url, {}, triggerFetch);

  const addCard = async () => {
   
    setTriggerFetch(prev => prev + 1);
    
    setCards(cards => [...cards, { ...data.response, id: uuid() }]);
  };

  // Rest of your code.....
}
```